# What does Pentecostalism consider Prophetic Fine Art to be?

Tags: prophecy, art, pentecostalism

In many Pentecostal churches, they talk about prophetic art - pictures/paintings with prophetic value. And of course, the Catholic Church is full of art, but do they consider their churches art prophetic?

Is there any scripture on what is prophetic art? Does this make the artist a prophet?

Comment: Interested to see how they believe these are not graven images, as Catholics are often accused of 'worshiping'.

Comment: Is this a biblical basis question or a Pentecostalism question? You ask for "scripture on" but the question includes the Pentecostalism tag.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there's any example of prophetical art specifically but there is a Biblical basis for people being led by God to create art for example the Tabernacle and Temple in the OT (e.g. Exodus 31:1-5). In my mind, if someone is open to the Holy Spirit leading them to do things than it's not hard to imagine that they might create some art that has special significance because God led them to do it.

In terms of prophecy, I don't know of any example where a prophet in the Bible drew a picture though there are examples of prophets acting things, writing on walls, etc. all which are "artistic." To me the question of whether art can be prophetic isn't a big issue because in a sense anything can be prophetic.

Now whether that makes an artist a prophet - assuming you are referring to modern day and that you hold to a Pentecostal view that prophecy still "exists" - then generally the idea is this:

Anyone could create prophetic one time as led by the Spirit but not be a prophet. For someone to be a prophet they would have to regularly create prophetic art and generally people don't claim to be a prophet it's a designation given to them by their local church.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). In particular, answers here must focus on answering the specific question asked, rather than discussing related issues. See: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). For your answer to work here, you'd need to focus it on discussion *scripture* references on prophetic art.